# Tar Compaction activity on Adobe AEM repository is stuck

Tags: adobe, aem, revision

I am trying to perform a Revision Cleanup activity on AEM Repository to reduce the size of the same by Tar Compaction. The Repository Size is 730 GB and Adobe Version is 6.1 which is old. The estimated time is 7-8 hours for the activity to get completed. We ran it for 24 hours straight but the activity is still running and no output. We have also tried running all the commands to speed up the process but still it is taking time.
Kindly suggest an alternative to reduce the size of the repository.
Adobe does not provide support to older versions, so we cannot raise a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the memory assigned to your machine, RAM memory I mean for JVM. Maybe if you increase it will take less and finish.

The repository size is not big at all. Mine is more than 1TB and is working.

In order to clean your repo you can try to run the Garbage Collector directly from AEM on JMX console.

The only way to reduce the datastorage is compact the server, or delete content like big assets or also big packages. Create some queries to see which assets / packages are huge and also delete them.

Hope you can fix your issue.

Regards,